How do I make sure there are no remaining input resources in a hopper minecart for a 23 furnace super smelter?
In Minecraft 1.21.1: How do I make sure there are no remaining input resources in a hopper minecart for a 23 furnace super smelter?
I have currently built a super smelter utilizing Mumbo Jumbo's most recent design as seen in the latest season of Hermitcraft. While it works amazingly well for my single-player world, there's always a small amount left of the current input resource I put into it. While I don't care all that much about the issue for the fuel, as I'm just using coal I mine up to fuel it, it matters for the items I smelt as it might cause issues later down the line.
The circuit I'm using for this is one where the hopper minecart gets detected on the rear of the comparator that goes to turn off a redstone torch powering a sticky piston with a block holding the minecart. Another comparator to its right gives a minimum strength of 3 (hopper with 46 items in it on the right-side comparator's rear), and it turns off after having a minimum of 46 items in the minecart. Is there anything I can do to make it send just 46–47 items rather than a stack that leaves 28 items in the minecart?
Here's a visual on that I made in LibreSprite:


Having never built a super-smelter I'm not sure I exactly understand what you're trying to do. However, for isolating a "stack" of 46 items, you can use a decorated pot. A comparator listening to a decorated pot will output a signal with strength 11 when the pot contains 46 items, so you could use that to isolate 46 coal. I don't have a specific vision of how that could work, but it sounds like you have the technical expertise to create such a system.
